# Shadow overlaps ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to add shadow to `Toolbar` but it overlaps `ListView`'s items.
How can I make it transparent?

[image: Here bottom shadow overlapping list item]

Here bottom shadow overlapping list item.
I am using `View` with 9 patch drawable as shadow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white">
        ...
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_shadow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**I want shadow with transparent background**

Comment: what about `@android:color/transparent` color

Comment: If you don't want the shadow, simply remove it. The View with `android:background="@drawable/bottom_shadow"`

Comment: Show code for `bottom_shadow`

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want shadow you need to remove android:background="@drawable/bottom_shadow"

and add like:

android:background="#80000000
"

Comment: Nice try but i do need shadow, so that it have transparent background

Comment: please add your bottom_shadow.xml

Comment: I wrote that it is 9 patch png image

Comment: for transparency you need to add 80 before the hash code just like #80xxxxxx  x mean hash code for particular colour. hope you will understand..

Answer (score 0):

api > 21: need add this on ToolBar's xml attr

`android:elevation="0dp"`

api < 21: and this on current activity theme.

`<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

---

sorry for the wrong understand.

so here is a simple shadow with transparent background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#888"
      android:endColor="#8fff" android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: you can try this,save as bottom_shadow.xml